# Frustum culling on gpu

Tags: algorithm, graphics, gpu, shader

I am a 3D computer graphics learner and I want to implement frustum culling to work on the gpu. I've already implemented it with software rendering system. That culling worked with polygon with minimum of 3 vertices and, if it was outside the frustum, added a new point on the frustum inside. [Here is algorithm implementation just in case](https://github.com/TheArheus/3d-renderer/blob/Final-Ver/code/clipping.cpp#L51).

And, as I want to implement that algorithm on the gpu, I have several questions with it:

1. I was thinking to implement frustum culling with geometry shader, but that seems that I won't be able to cull UVs coordinates then, is it Right? Or there is a way to pass, somehow, those UV's coordinates, cull them in geometry shader, and pass them next to the fragment shader?
2. I thought to implement it in vertex shader, but won't I be able to get all vertices for current triangle? Maybe I just don't quite know a way to corretly get all vertices per face? Wouldn't I just to cull only one by one vertex?

Maybe I just don't know the right way to implement frustum culling on gpu. Can there be a better algorithm to implement frustum culling? Thanks.

Comment: In geometry shader you have access to anything that is passed from vertex ... so if you pass the UV from vertex to geometry then you have access to them ....

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you have implemented is *'clipping'*.

'*frustum culling*' usually refers to a technique where you discard invisible elements as a whole and I believe that is not what you are asking here.

back to clipping,

Graphics API by default will clip polygons in normalized device coordinate space. For example with OpenGL, out side of 2x2x2 cube with center at (0,0,0) will be clipped automatically after the vertex shader.